# charts_flutter - custom scale for domain axis

Tags: android, flutter

I am new to development and I came across this rather tricky situation.

---

The domain axis of my graph has only six ticks which are,

```
{250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000}
```

[my current graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hrgsp.png)

if you can notice, you can see there is so much space between 4,000 and 8,000 in the domain axis (x-axis). attaching the code snippet I used to achieve the custom static ticks

```
  final staticTicks = <charts.TickSpec<double>>[
    new charts.TickSpec(250),
    new charts.TickSpec(500),
    new charts.TickSpec(1000),
    new charts.TickSpec(2000),
    new charts.TickSpec(4000),
    new charts.TickSpec(8000),
  ];

  domainAxis: new charts.NumericAxisSpec(
    tickProviderSpec: new charts.StaticNumericTickProviderSpec(staticTicks),
  ),
```

now I need help in removing that space, and making the six ticks evenly spaced out in the x - axis (domain axis)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is to use a logarithmic scale for your domain axis.

[image]

### Full source code:

```
import 'dart:math' show Random, pow, log, exp;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PointsLineChart.withSampleData(),
    );
  }
}

/// Line chart example

class PointsLineChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series> seriesList;
  final bool animate;

  PointsLineChart(this.seriesList, {this.animate});

  /// Creates a [LineChart] with sample data and no transition.
  factory PointsLineChart.withSampleData() {
    return new PointsLineChart(
      _createSampleData(),
      // Disable animations for image tests.
      animate: false,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final staticTicks = <charts.TickSpec<double>>[
      new charts.TickSpec(log(250)),
      new charts.TickSpec(log(500)),
      new charts.TickSpec(log(1000)),
      new charts.TickSpec(log(2000)),
      new charts.TickSpec(log(4000)),
      new charts.TickSpec(log(8000)),
    ];
    return new charts.LineChart(
      seriesList,
      animate: animate,
      defaultRenderer: new charts.LineRendererConfig(includePoints: true),
      domainAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec(
        tickProviderSpec: charts.StaticNumericTickProviderSpec(staticTicks),
        tickFormatterSpec: charts.BasicNumericTickFormatterSpec(
            (measure) => exp(measure).round().toString()),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Create one series with sample hard coded data.
  static List<charts.Series<MyData, double>> _createSampleData() {
    final random = Random();
    final data = List.generate(
      6,
      (index) => MyData(
        250 * pow(2, index),
        index * 100 + random.nextInt(100),
      ),
    );
    print(data.map((element) => '${log(element.x)} - ${element.y}'));

    return [
      new charts.Series<MyData, double>(
        id: 'Data',
        colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
        domainFn: (MyData item, _) => log(item.x),
        measureFn: (MyData item, _) => item.y,
        data: data,
      )
    ];
  }
}

/// Sample linear data type.
class MyData {
  final int x;
  final int y;

  MyData(this.x, this.y);
}
```

Comment: this worked flawlessly, +1 for the logic, I never would've come up with that