# charts_flutter - reduce distance between two dates

Tags: flutter, dart, charts

I use charts_flutter, I want to do a TimeSeriesChart where the DateTime is not distant.
[The result I have for the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMbWK.png)
See on the picture, the last point is very far and i want the same distance between each points.

I have find that but it only work for numerical and not fo DateTime.
[charts_flutter - custom scale for domain axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66236456/charts-flutter-custom-scale-for-domain-axis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want the domain axis to be linear, not respecting the actual values of the `DateTime`. See [this example](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/line_charts/simple). Arrange your points into a simple array (indexed by 0, 1, 2, 3...) as in the example. This will ensure equal spacing. Then provide custom labeling for the domain axis to format the specific dates that the point represent. (Note that non-linear axes can lead to confusion for the viewer.)

Comment: I can't find how to make a custom label, do you have a link for that? I thank you.

Comment: Use a tick formatter spec. For example https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/axes/statically_provided_ticks.html

Comment: Thanks you so much for your answer. Finally I use that https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/combo_charts/ordinal_bar_line
I just remove Bar.